# What is a problem with Git and LFS in my case?

Tags: git, git-lfs

There is a git repo and I cloned it locally. Then I open Visual Studio and open my project. When I try to build it I got such errors -

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: TV_FFmpeg, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>cl : Command line warning D9030: '/Gm' is incompatible with multiprocessing; ignoring /MP switch
1>TV_FFmpegEncoder_WithContainer.cpp
1>D:\_repo\co_main\_ExtLibs\ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-dev_and_shared-lgpl\include\libavcodec/avcodec.h(1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\_repo\co_main\_ExtLibs\ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-dev_and_shared-lgpl\include\libavcodec/avcodec.h(1): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'https'
1>D:\_repo\co_main\_ExtLibs\ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-dev_and_shared-lgpl\include\libavcodec/avcodec.h(2): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\_repo\co_main\_ExtLibs\ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-dev_and_shared-lgpl\include\libavcodec/avcodec.h(2): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'sha256'
1>D:\_repo\co_main\_ExtLibs\ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-dev_and_shared-lgpl\include\libavcodec/avcodec.h(2): error C2059: syntax error: 'user-defined literal'
1>D:\_repo\co_main\_ExtLibs\ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-dev_and_shared-lgpl\include\libavutil/opt.h(2): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>D:\_repo\co_main\_ExtLibs\ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-dev_and_shared-lgpl\include\libavutil/opt.h(2): error C2086: 'int oid': redefinition
1>D:\_repo\co_main\_ExtLibs\ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-dev_and_shared-lgpl\include\libavcodec/avcodec.h(2): note: see declaration of 'oid'
```

Ok, I see that issue in `avcodec.h` file I open this file and I see that there is no content inside and instead only these lines :

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:887dd51572e3f726cd6891ecf02e0008780f7053517aef841950ddfa62
size 216439
```

This link `https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1` lead to git web site with lfs description. First of all I thought maybe I don't have LFS installed on my PC, and it is a reason why I had not got these files after `git clone`, but I found this answer

https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/901

and tried this command

```
git lfs env
```

and output was -

```
Endpoint=https://myrepo@bitbucket.org/myuser/mait.git/info/lfs (auth=basic)
LocalWorkingDir=D:\_repo\co_main
LocalGitDir=D:\_repo\co_main\.git
LocalGitStorageDir=D:\_repo\co_main\.git
LocalMediaDir=D:\_repo\co_main\.git\lfs\objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=D:\_repo\co_main\.git\lfs\tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=8
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=D:\_repo\co_main\.git\lfs
AccessDownload=basic
AccessUpload=basic
DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file
GIT_EXEC_PATH=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
GIT_LFS_PATH=C:\Program Files\Git LFS
GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```

so it means that I have LFS on my PC.

Question is - what am I doing wrong? How to get all files with their content properly?

Comment: I think if you installed git lfs after you pulled that repository you might need some combination of `git lfs install` and `git lfs pull` to make sure all the hooks are set up correctly and everything has been downloaded, but I'm not sure, I've not used lfs a lot myself.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks man!!:)) You was right! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it